# Expressing standard coordinates of a point with respect to basis

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I express the standard coordinates (x, y) of a point in R2 in terms of its coordinates with respect to the basis B={[1 2], [-3 4]}?

I'm confused on the terminology here. I know that the matrix S=[1-3 24] is the transition matrix for a vector from the basis to the standard basis (S[x]_B = x), but don't know what to do from there.

Answer (score 2):

If the point's coordinates with respect to $B$ are $(u,v)$, then
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -3 \\ 2 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v \end{bmatrix}$$
gives you its standard coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients of the vector $(x, y)$ in base $B$ is equal to the product $S (x, y)^{ T} $.

Answer (score 0):

$a\begin {bmatrix} 1\\2 \end {bmatrix} + b\begin {bmatrix} -3\\4 \end {bmatrix} = \begin {bmatrix} 1\\0 \end {bmatrix}$

Solve for $a,b$ and we will have an expression of one principal component vector of the standard basis in terms of the basis $B.$  Then do the same thing for the other principal component vector.

Alternatively:

$\begin {bmatrix} 1 & - 3 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf v$ would represent a vector in $B$ in terms of the standard basis.

$\begin {bmatrix} 1 & - 3 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\mathbf v$  would represent a vector in the standard basis in terms of the basis $B.$